# Could not find pubspec.yaml in unittest 0.11.0+5

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I'm running pub get and its reporting that it can't find a pubspec.yaml file in unittest package, anyone seen this before? Im on Dart Editor version 1.8.0.dev_00_00 (DEV) Dart SDK version 1.8.0-dev.0.0

Comment: Have you tried `pub cache repair` (from the console)?

Comment: C:\Program Files\dart\dart-sdk\bin>pub cache repair
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Roaming\P
ub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\unittest-0.11.0+5".

Comment: I'll try manually deleting the cache and starting again, but this pub cache business seems really flakey, I was having problems with it a few months ago too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The downloaded package in

`C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\unittest-0.11.0+5`

didn't have a pubspec.yaml file in it, and using `pub cache repair` wouldn't work for that very reason also so I had to manually open the directory and delete it then when I did a new `pub get` it did work. Sounds like `cache repair` might need tweaking to make it delete any corrupted packages that didnt have their pubspecs downloaded with them and I beleive this broken state was created by me running a `pub get` whislt a `pub get` was already in progress on the same pubspec.yaml  file, so probably best you avoid doing that.

Comment: [done](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21408&thanks=21408&ts=1414145136), cheers